# Spring WebSockets - Broken pipe when browser abruptly closes connection

Tags: spring-websocket

I'm facing an issue with spring-wesockets here. When the page gets refreshed, the server throws an IOException caused by the broken pipe.

Thinking as a server, this is a normal behavior. But thinking as a client its normal to refresh page or go away.

The config:

```
<websocket:message-broker application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/wsock"/>
    <websocket:simple-broker prefix="/topic,/queue"/>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

Since I'm using SimpleBroker, is there a way to catch and handle the exception?

Comment: You need to provide more information. [Also, please read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, i thought that it was clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Spring 4.0.3 (due march 25th) should fix your problem.

This is a [known issue with the servlet spec](https://java.net/jira/browse/SERVLET_SPEC-44) (you can vote for it to be resolved). Spring 4.0.3 is changing the logging strategy for this - see issue [SPR-11438](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11438).